# Site Stats Zeroed in Public Betas

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-exchange, beta-phase, site-stats

[Site Stats Zeroed in Public Betas http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/8340/statszeroed.png](http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/8340/statszeroed.png)

---

It seems that this problem is affecting **all** public beta sites, except for:

- Game Development
- Electronic Gadgets
- Geographic Information Systems
- Mathematics

Comment: Wow, what a terrible site. ;)

Comment: That freehand circle looks like it's actually part of the site.

Comment: Looks like a Bézier curve.

Comment: This has been reported before, by the way; I thought it was `[status-completed]`, though.

Comment: @popular: I already asked him about his freehand circles. He says it's because he uses a Mac, so his freehand circles are more smooth. Personally, I think he's a robot trying to infiltrate meta.

Comment: @dev: He is obviously cheating.

Comment: @Popular Last time was isolated to a specific site. This time it appears to be affecting every site, though.

Comment: @Grace, you have one heck of a memory for MSO posts.  I'll just stop searching for that link and take your word for it.

Comment: @Popular Looks like it's just a luck factor which determines which sites do and do not get desynced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reported this on one of the beta meta sites.  Per Jeff it is normal behavior immediately after a deployment.

[Site stats broken?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198/site-stats-broken)

Answer (score 2):

Will go away in 10 minutes.

edit: since this question keeps coming up, I changed the stats so they will say

```
loading
...
...
...
...
```

instead of all zeros. Hopefully that's clearer that the solution is to sit tight and wait 10 minutes.

(although, this could persist longer than 10 minutes if API is down for some catastrophic reason)

Comment: didn't you mean 6 to 8 weeks?